# Send facebook app request to pre selected facebook contact

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5, ios6, ios4

I want to send the facebook app request to preselected facebook friend. is it possible? right now i am following send request [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/search?path=&selection=Send%20Requests%20on%20iOS). In this it shows request and list of facebook friends. what i want is something like following image[image]

any help is appreciated.

Comment: From where will you get these pre-selected friends? And you dont want to show the friend selector? If so, you have to make your own control and use the apis, instead of this simple technique of sending the requests.

Comment: do you have tutorial link for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the normal Request Dialog - [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

You just have to provide the `to` parameter with the request, eg:

```
to=FRIEND1,FRIEND2,FRIEND3
```

Here's a direct URL, you can test first:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?
>     app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
>     message=MyMessage&
>     redirect_uri=LINK_TO_YOUR_APP&to=FRIEND1,FRIEND2,FRIEND3

Comment: Unfortunately in this case, the app request gets into the app center and doesn't show up in the top notification panel on facebook. But the default FB Web Dialogs in iOS lets you achieve this but can't be pre-populated with a list of friends.

Comment: I didn't tried this, but I tried with one of my apps which is not listed in the app centre; and with this request the user is redirected to the app itself.

Comment: Yeah, if the request is opened on the device (on Facebook App) then ofcourse it will surely open up the app itself on your device (if the app exists on device), because facebook app is linked to an identifier (com.yourcompanyNane.productName) but what he or she is looking for is preselected friend list with notifications on facebook, which can't be done with silent apprequests. It can be done only through FB Dialogs but friends can't be preselected.

Comment: Not the silent request I'm talking of, but dialogs only (but with pre-selected friends). Did you tried the url I posted?